# How can I display a matrix table in asp.net mvc3 with not set many to many?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, matrix

my question is very similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647786/how-can-i-display-a-matrix-table-in-asp-net-mvc3)

I have three tables which are in a many to many relationship. I have to build a matrix that will give the possibility to set the between table. In contrast with the other question, I don't have the **Sales** values yet, but I need to build the same grid format.

I'm not sure about how to write the LINQ query and the one in the other article did not work for my purpose.

Thank you for your help,

### EDIT

To answer to Mirko: The other query did not work because I got no result. This is cause by having no data in the between table. I should be able to have the matrix based on the Product and SalesPerson with empty value (or not) for the between table.

Answer (score 0):

Simply distinct over the bridge and enumerate (in controller):

```
var model = new MyModel();
model.Columns = resultSet.Select(x => x.ColumnProperty).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x);
model.Rows = resultSet.Select(x => x.RowProperty).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x);
```

Then in View:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>
      <td></td>
      @foreach(var column in Model.Columns)
      {
        <td>@column</td>
      }
    </th>
  </thead>
  @foreach(var row in Model.Rows)
  {
    <tr>
      <td>@row</td>
      @foreach(var column in Model.Columns)
      {
        <td></td>
      }
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

This is assuming you never need the sales, otherwise you will need to build that out.

If this is not it, please spell out better in what way the other question query did not work for you.